# When sessions are closed in mysql when creating a sqlalchemy session

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I still have sessions hibernating, although after creating the session, I closed it with both session.close() and session.remove().
BUT mysql sessions in sleep state close them themselves after a random time

I want to know:

1. How to manage closing sessions
2. Who closes sleep sessions
3. Why close() and remove() don't work

Comment: Connections are pooled: closing a session does not remove it from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy (ORM) "sessions" and MySQL "sessions" are not the same thing.

A SQLAlchemy session is a mechanism that manages a collection of ORM objects. We can create new objects and add them to the session, we can retrieve existing objects from the database into the session, and we can also update and delete objects in the session. When we call `session.commit()` all of those changes are sent to the database via a SQLAlchemy "connection". When a new database connection is established it creates a MySQL "session" on the server. Therefore, the MySQL "session" is more closely related to the SQLAlchemy "connection" than it is to the SQLAlchemy "session".

The MySQL dialect for SQLAlchemy uses [connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html) by default. When a SQLAlchemy session is "closed" the underlying database connection is not closed; it is returned to the connection pool. Therefore the MySQL "session" continues to exist.

> How to manage closing sessions

To manage SQLAlchemy sessions, use a context manager, e.g.,

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.add(…)
    sess.commit()
```

We usually don't try to manage MySQL sessions directly, because …

> Who closes sleep sessions

The MySQL server will close sessions after they have been idle for a while.

> Why close() and remove() don't work

They do work, just not the way you expect.